# Размер картинок для смарфонов

Tags: html, разрешение

У меня на сайте есть галерея картинок. Картинки в довольно хорошем качестве, где-то 2000х1500. Я заметил, что довольно много посетителей с телефонов быстро просматривают картинки, то есть им не нужна большая детализация, но они грузят излишний трафик и ждут лишнее время.

Появилась идея грузить на мобильные картинки меньшего размера и сделать им кнопку "показывать картинки в большом размере" для тех, кому это необходимо.

Технически это не сложно. Вопрос в другом - какого размера показывать картинки по-умолчанию для мобильных? Что бы они были во весь экран усредненного мобильного?

Спасибо!

Comment: Даже не буду спрашивать, как Вы качество картинок определяете через разрешение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё зависит от используемого телефона и его разрешения. 
Вы можете посмотреть размеры разрешений для разных моделей телефонов 
[Тут](http://myresolutionis.ru/page/smapage.php) 
Соответственно при помощи `@media` Вы можете для телефонов с большим разрешение оставить текущие картинки, а для тех телефонов, что с разрешением меньше определённого(Тоже через @media указывается ширина), например, `1280×720`, выводить картинки уже меньшего размера. 
 Диагонали телефонов быстро растут, так что сложно чётко предугадать возможные размеры. 
Если очень хочется, можно распределить их на несколько групп.
Наиболее популярными в `@media` являются:

```
/* Large desktops and laptops */
media (min-width: 1200px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and medium desktops */
media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
media (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and smaller */
media (max-width: 480px) {

}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но я спрашивал совершенно о другом. установить css для размера можно разными способами, я же не хочу загружать большую картинку в браузер тем, кому это не нужно. 
то есть, вопрос теоретический - какого размера картинки имеет смысл загружать для пользователей с мобильными устройствами.

Comment: @user285153 Тогда Ваш вопрос лишён логики. Любую картинку можно растянуть на весь экран, хоть 320×480, по факту разница будет исключительно в качестве изображения. Один телефон имеет размеры минимальные - другой имеет размеры планшета. И как раз об этом я Вам и написал Выше.